# Set Color of UIActivityIndicatorView of a UIRefreshControl?

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, uirefreshcontrol

Is there a way to set the color of the activity indicator (probably `UIActivityIndicatorView`) of a `UIRefreshControl`?

I was able to set the color of the 'rubber' and the indicator:

```
[_refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:55.0f/255.0f blue:152.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

But I want to have the 'rubber' blue and the activity indicator white, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not officially supported, but if you want to risk future iOS changes breaking your code you can try this:

Building off ayoy's answer, I built a subclass of UIRefreshControl, which sets the color of the ActivityIndicator in `beginRefresing`. This should be a better place to put this, since you may call this in code instead of a user causing the animation to begin.

```
@implementation WhiteRefreshControl : UIRefreshControl

- (void)beginRefreshing
{
    [super beginRefreshing];

    NSArray *subviews = [[[self subviews] lastObject] subviews];
    //Range check on subviews
    if (subviews.count > 1) 
    {
        id spinner = [subviews objectAtIndex:1];
        //Class check on activity indicator
        if ([spinner isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) 
        {
            UIActivityIndicatorView *spinnerActivity = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)spinner;
            spinnerActivity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Very good and reusable :)
Also thanks to ayoy for the initial idea :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `[super beginRefreshing];` at the end, or at some point?

Comment: This relies on the hierarchy of the `UIRefreshControl` remaining unchanged - which is not guaranteed by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you technically can do it, but it's not supported. You better follow Dave's suggestion, or read on if you insist.

If you investigate subviews of `UIRefreshControl` it turns out that it contains one subview, of class `_UIRefreshControlDefaultContentView`.

If you then check subviews of that content view in refreshing state, it contains the following:

- `UILabel`
- `UIActivityIndicatorView`
- `UIImageView`
- `UIImageView`

So **technically** in your callback to `UIControlEventValueChanged` event you can do something like this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[[[self.refreshControl subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
```

And that would work. It also doesn't violate App Review Guidelines as it doesn't use private API (browsing subviews of a view and playing with them using public API is legal).
But keep in mind that the internal implementation of `UIRefreshControl` can change anytime and your code may not work or even crash in later versions of iOS.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I copied you code, it is not working... It seems that there is no UIActivityIndicator inside, but:

    for (id v in [[[_refreshControl subviews] lastObject] subviews])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [v class]);
    }

Gives me: UILabel, UIImageView, UIImageView

Comment: As I stated in the answer, you have to call that in a callback to UIControlEventValueChanged. Then it gets the UIActivityIndicatorView.

Comment: I'm using this same method, but just thought it would be worth mentioning you should use some checks (range and class) in case apple decides to change how `UIRefreshControl` is organized in the future.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.  You'll need to file [an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) to ask Apple to implement this.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have opened an enhancement request with Apple! ID: 13870593